# how can i get the text from within the div?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, events, event-handling

```
const questions = (props) => {
  const { question, options, id } = props.quiz;

  const selected = (e) => {
    e.target.children[0].checked = true;
    console.log(e.target);
  };

  return (
    <div className="bg-gray-200 p-6 m-10 rounded-md">
      <div className="font-bold text-xl text-slate-600">{question}</div>
      <div className="grid grid-cols-2 mt-4">
        {options.map((option) => (
          <div className="border-2 border-solid border-gray-400 rounded  text-gray-500 m-1">
            <div className="flex cursor-pointer p-3" id={id} onClick={selected}>
              <input type="radio" className="mr-2" name="name" />
              {option}
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default questions;
```

[image]

if console.log(e.target) is done in the selected function return the Div. How can I access the text of the Div within the selected function?

Comment: You already have the `options` data, simply get the `id` of the checkbox and get the element in the options array that matches the id

Comment: You shouldn't just make random divs clickable. Use a label associated with the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the text of the Div within the selected function by using the `.textContent` property on the `e.target` object. This will return the text content of the Div that was clicked.

```
const selected = (e) => {
    e.target.children[0].checked = true;
    console.log(e.target.textContent);
  };
```